# Javascript onclick events are not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want this :
When you click the lesson, there'll be chart of that lesson .. for example: 
when you click math radio button .. there will be chart of math .. then, when you click p.e. radio button .. chart of math will be hidden and p.e. will visible ..

My Javascript code ..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function charts(firstchart, seconchart, thirdchart, fourthchart){
    document.getElementById(firstchart).style.display='inline';
    document.getElementById(secondchart).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(thirdchart).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById(fourthchart).style.display='none';      
}
</script>
```

And my CSS Part ..

```
<style>
#chart_div {width: 900px; height: 500px;display:none;}
#chart_div1 {width: 900px; height: 500px;display:none;}
#chart_div2 {width: 900px; height: 500px;display:none;}
#chart_div3 {width: 900px; height: 500px;display:none;}
</style>
```

And My Body Part ...

```
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<div id="chart_div3"></div>
<form action="">
<input name="ali" type="radio" onclick="charts(chart_div, chart_div1, chart_div2, chart_div3)" />Math <br>
<input name="ali" type="radio" onclick="charts(chart_div1, chart_div, chart_div2, chart_div3)" />English <br>
<input name="ali" type="radio" onclick="charts(chart_div2, chart_div1, chart_div, chart_div3)" />Biology <br>
<input name="ali" type="radio" onclick="charts(chart_div3, chart_div1, chart_div2, chart_div)" />P.E. <br>
</form>
```

And I took charts script from [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) ..

Comment: And what's your problem/question?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: kindly explain how we help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id should be into quotes and you are using without quotes,

Should be something like this.

```
onclick="charts('chart_div', 'chart_div1', 'chart_div2', 'chart_div3')"
```